# MongoDB query document that doesn't have a given entry?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
  "address": {
     "building": "1007",
     "coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
     "street": "Morris Park Ave",
     "zipcode": "10462"
  },
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
     { "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
     { "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

I want a query that looks at the `grades.grade` and `grades.score` and doesn't return a this document if a `grades` object has `grade == "A"` AND `score == 2`.  However, I want it to return a document if for example one `grades` object has `grade == "A"` and another `grades` object has `score == 2`.

This might also illustrate what I'm trying to do (although it doesn't work):

```
db.restaurants.find({
    grades : {
        $and: [
            {"grade": {'$ne':"A"}}, 
            {"score": {'$ne':2}}
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query.

You basically require `$and`ing `$or` and `$nand`. MongoDB doesn't have `$nand` operator, so I replaced it with the equivalent experession.

```
db.restaurants.find({
    $and: [{
        $or: [{
            "grades.grade": "A"
        }, {
            "grades.score": 2
        }]
    }, {
        $nor: [{
            $and: [{
                "grades.grade": "A"
            }, {
                "grades.score": 2
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

`$or` operation will match all documents where any of the grade embedded document has either grade `A` or score is `2`.

```
{ "grade": "A", "score": 3 } --- Just grade A

{ "grade": "A", "score": 2 } --- Both grade A and score 2

{ "grade": "B", "score": 2 } --- Just score 2
```

`$nand` operation will match all the documents where none of the grade embedded documents has both grade as `A` and score is `2`

```
{ "grade": "A", "score": 3 } --- Just grade A

{ "grade": "B", "score": 2 } --- Just score 2

{ "grade": "C", "score": 4 } --- None
```

`$and` of above operations is the intersection.

```
{ "grade": "A", "score": 3 } --- Just grade A

{ "grade": "B", "score": 2 } --- Just score 2
```

Comment: This seems to work but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.  Do you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: Thanks!  Took me a second to understand it.  That's fancy stuff and really helpful.  Really, thanks!